# Creating markers with an icon of type google.maps.Symbol sometimes gives an error "Invalid value for property <icon>"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I noticed some weird behavior when trying out vector icons in Maps API 3.9 as described here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#VectorIcons

I created a test page (http://www.foxden.nl/test/symboltest1.html) with a vector icon which runs fine.

However, in a second test (http://www.foxden.nl/test/symboltest2.html) I left away the script that draws the marker. When I then use Firefox's web console to add the marker, I get the following:

```
[16:03:18.483]     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922),
                     icon: {
                       path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                       scale: 10
                     },
                     draggable: true,
                     map: map
                     });
[16:03:18.486] Error: Invalid value for property <icon>: [object Object]
```

It works fine in Chrome's web console, but not in Firefox's console. And it's the exact same code.

In a GWT application I get the same behavior. I have this function:

```
private native void createMarker(GoogleMap map, LatLng position) /*-{
    var marker = new $wnd.google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        icon: {
            path: $wnd.google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 10
        },
        map: map
    });
}-*/;
```

Which gives me the same error:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (Error): Invalid value for property <icon>: [object Object]
```

Why does this happen, and is there any way I can avoid this problem?